# How take over a draggable image in a pre-existing canvas creating a new one

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, html5-canvas

I'm spending a bit of time to develop a script which post an image in a canvas, and if I want, a draggable div could be attached and incorpored in that canvas and, finally, I can download it as a unique image (the subtype image that was the first one image uploaded in the canvas ... the second one should be the image contained in a draggable div).

So the result should be a single downloaded image that includes the image of the draggable div overlapped to the canvas image. I hope to be clear in my description.

I post below the code scripted until now, missing the last one operation...

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery UI Draggable e Resizable- ETt.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

    <style>
    #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
    #resizable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
    #resizable h3 { text-align: center; margin: 0; }
    </style>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
        $( function() {
         $('#file-input').change(function(e) {
        var file = e.target.files[0],
        imageType = /image.*/;
        if (!file.type.match(imageType))
         return;

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = fileOnload;
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

     });

function fileOnload(e) {
        var $img = $('<img>', { src: e.target.result });
        var canvas = $('#canvas')[0];
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

         $img.load(function() {
         context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
     });
      }

     $('#draggable').draggable();
     $('#image').resizable();

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
     ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    function downloadCanvas(link, canvasId, filename) {
       link.href = document.getElementById(canvasId).toDataURL();
      link.download = filename;
        }

    document.getElementById('download').addEventListener('click', function() {
    downloadCanvas(this, 'canvas', 'test.png');
    }, false);

  } );

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="draggable"  style="display:inline-block" >
<img id="image" src="picexample.png" /> 
</div><br> 
<input type="file" id="file-input"><br><br> <a id="download">Download as image</a>
<br><br>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500px" height="500px"></canvas>
<br><br>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can solve the dropping phase, the real problem is having the download of the figure that has absorbed the dropped image in the canvas over the previous image in the canvas...Thank you in advance to all can help me!

Comment: I don't think Jquery would work for this. You would have to use a canvas library or code a draggable rectangle using canvas API.